# How to play music in background Tkinter with winsound

Tags: python, audio, tkinter

I am trying to make a program and have the pokemon theme in the background while tkinter is running. But the program doesnt start before the song is over. How can I make that python keeps winsound active while running the rest of the program.'

```
winsound.PlaySound('song.wav', winsound.SND_ALIAS)
```

This is what I have. After this the code the whole program starts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`winsound.SND_ASYNC`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/winsound.html#winsound.SND_ASYNC) to make the call return immediatly:

```
winsound.PlaySound('song.wav', winsound.SND_ALIAS | winsound.SND_ASYNC)
```